# How to ensure that all data are read from a NetworkStream

Tags: c#, tcp, networkstream

Is sure that all data are read from a  NetworkStream when DataAvailable is false?

Or does the sender of the data have to send the length of the data first.
And I have to read until I have read the number of bytes specified by the sender?

Sampel:

```
private Byte[] ReadStream(NetworkStream ns)
{
    var bl = new List<Byte>();
    var receivedBytes = new Byte[128];
    while (ns.DataAvailable)
    {
            var bytesRead = ns.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length);
            if (bytesRead == receivedBytes.Length)
                bl.AddRange(receivedBytes);
            else
                bl.AddRange(receivedBytes.Take(bytesRead));
    }
    return bl.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataAvailable` just tells you what is buffered and available locally. It means *exactly nothing* in terms of what is likely to arrive. The most common use of `DataAvailable` is to decide between a sync read and an async read.

If you are expecting the inbound stream to *close* after the send, then you can just keep using `Read` until a non-positive result is achieved, which tells you it has reached the end. If they are sending multiple frames, or just aren't closing - then yes: you'll need some way of detecting the end of a frame (=logical message). That *can* be via a length-prefix and counting, but it can also be via sentinel values. For example, in text-based protocols, `\n` or `\r` are often interpreted as "end of message".

So: it depends entirely on your protocol.

Comment: Thx.  I’ll use a length-prefix (Because of the sender doesn’t close the stream)

Comment: Marc , I don't understand : does the sender has to `close` or can he just do `flush` ? I'm asking because I'm sending `person` from java ( using protocol buffers) to my C# app and in the c# I read while `DataAvailable` and it does work....so am I doing it wrong ? ( which will be weird because it does working).

Comment: @Royi DataAvailable === 0 does not tell you anything about the overall stream. It indicates neither the end of a frame nor the stream. The **only** thing it means is: right now, there is nothing in the receive buffer. In casual testing, this will generally appear to be the same thing as "the end of a frame", etc. However, this is **not** what it actually means, and it *will* fail. Like threading, however, making it *demonstrably and repeatably* fail is more tricky than it sounds, especially on a LAN and when using small payloads.

Comment: @Royi alternative visualisation: you are one side of a door, and your friend is the other. He has a book you want, but it is too big. So he is tearing out each page and posting it through the letter slot. When you stop seeing pages, you bind the book. It is all going well for the first few chapters until your friend stops for half a second to tie his shoelace. You stopped seeing ready pages so you walked away. Your book now ends half way through, mid sentence.

Comment: So , I must ( after serialization) - to see how many bytes the whole message is - and then send this number PRIOR to the message ?

Comment: @Royi yes, that is a common way of doing it.

Comment: Marc, there is a hidden problem because if the friend on the other side sends me 4 bytes of the length - there might be an endien bom problem - so how can he send me those 4 bytes so it will be safe for me to read the right value ?

Comment: @Royi which is why network protocols usually state their endianness in the specification. If both ends know that the 4 bytes need to be little-endian, then it doesn't matter what the CPUs are.

Comment: @Marc Garvell That is the most intuitive description ever :). So does the network protocol for typical C# NetworkStream specify their endianess (such that I need not bother about endianess when reading and writing from the network stream)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have a start/end character, so the message would be:

```
string message = "Hello";
string messageToSend = (char)2 + message + (char)3;
```

Comment: "best" is subjective and depends on a lot of factors. For example, from the OP's code it is impossible to know whether they are using a text protocol vs a binary protocol; if it is a binary protocol, sentinel values like this become very unreliable.

Comment: @MarcGravell let me refrase, the easiest but effective way( as far as I know)

Comment: It's not quite that easy. You have to organise escaping of the sentinel values, and and of the escape character itself,and undo it at the receiver. Not that difficult, but I've seen a lot of people make a meal of it.