# TCP socket server depending on service broker, how can I receive entire message and send response?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sockets, tcp, sqldependency

I am setting up an application that needs to do a couple things... 1.) Receive a string of xml data from a tcp socket. 2.) Insert this data into a sql table. 3.) Triggers update numerous things in these tables and throw them into an output table. 4.) Sql Dependencies acknowledge that a record has been inserted into the output table and will need to send a reply through the same socket.

The problem I am running into is this, if I get the entire message sent to the server from the client, I have to `.Close` the client side, which makes it impossible to receive a response, if I don't `.Close` the client side, I can receive responses as long as the message fits into one packet (message being received by the server is cut off if it's too long and therefor throws an error). How can I make this work? So at a loss right now, if there is any additional information needed to help this work let me know. I am nearing the deadline for this program and would REALLY like to make it work.

#### Here is my client code:

```
private void SendMessage(string input, TcpClient client)
{
    // Ensure some xml data has been provided.
    string Error = string.Empty;
    if (input == string.Empty)
    {
        Error += "You cannot send an empty xml string\r";
        Textbox_FauxXMLSend.Focus();
    }

    // Prompt user to correct data if needed.
    if (Error != string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Error, "Send XML", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        // Send and receive the provided xml data.
        using (NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input + "\0");
            networkStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            networkStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            Textbox_FauxXMLReceive.Text += (returndata) + "\n";
        }
        _requestCount++;
        lblRequestCount.Text = string.Format("Request Count: {0}", _requestCount.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Send Message Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        CloseConnection(client);
    }
}
```

#### The receiving end of the server:

```
private void ReceivePortMessages()
{
    string debug = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        Debug.Print(" >> Starting Server");
        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        _TcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, TcpPort); ;
        Debug.Print(string.Format("{0}:{1}", ipAddress.ToString(), TcpPort.ToString()));
        _TcpListener.Start();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        do
        {
            try
            {
                _TcpClient = _TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Debug.Print(" >> Accept connection from client");
                NetworkStream networkStream = _TcpClient.GetStream();
                int receivingBufferSize = (int)_TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize;
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[receivingBufferSize];
                int Read = 0;
                string dataFromClient = string.Empty;
                if (!sw.IsRunning)
                {
                    sw.Start();
                }

                Read = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, receivingBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("\0"));
                if (dataFromClient != string.Empty)
                {
                    XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
                    debug = dataFromClient;
                    xm.LoadXml(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", dataFromClient));
                    XmlElement root = xm.DocumentElement;
                    string rootName = root.FirstChild.Name;
                    RouteInboundXML(rootName, dataFromClient, sw);
                    sw.Restart();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
                _TcpClient.Close();
                _TcpListener.Stop();
                ErrorLog.Write("XmlProcessing", ex.ToString() + "\r\n" + "DataFromClient: " + debug, "ReceivePortMessages()");
                return;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
        ErrorLog.Write("XmlProcessing", ex.ToString(), "ReceivePortMessages()");
    }
}
```

#### And the send of the server which is invoked after an `SqlDependency` action has fired and appropriate data has been generated:

```
private void SendReply(string reply)
{
    try
    {
        NetworkStream networkStream = _TcpClient.GetStream();
        string serverResponse = reply;
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
        Debug.Print(" >> " + serverResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        ErrorLog.Write("XmlProcessing", ex.ToString(), "SendReply()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of code to go through, and I'm a little slow :), but just a first glance....at a minimum, shouldn't the client portion that does the reading back from the server be in some sort of loop, checking the boolean DataAvailable property to guarantee all data is read?

Comment: Actually, the use of DataAvailable may prove incomplete - take a look at this post re what at least *sounds* like a similar situation and the use of sentinel characters for positive detection of EOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709781/how-to-ensure-that-all-data-are-read-from-a-networkstream

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am running into is this, if I get the entire message sent to the server from the client, I have to .Close the client side, which makes it impossible to receive a response

Ofcourse, client wouldn't receive response if you `close` socket on sending message to server.

> if I don't .Close the client side, I can receive responses as long as the message fits into one packet (message being received by the server is cut off if it's too long and therefor throws an error).

TCP is stream protocol and does not maintain message boundaries.Your client cannot assume that response from server will fit in one packet.It should know about the server response. For this server and client should have an agreement. Like:

> how many bytes does the response take? Put this info in the messages getting exchanged.
>
> Markers enclosing the response message - Start of message and end of message.

Based on this knowledge, client should "anticipate" the response which can be come over multiple `read` operations. So in affect, you cannot have only one `read`. You should keep calling `read` until the required number of bytes are read as per application level understanding.

Comment: This answer has received a down vote. I am interested in knowing the incorrectness in the answer. If one down-voter can can point me the reason, I would be glad.

Comment: Mine as well. I think we have a "serial downvoter" here. Alas :)

Comment: Yes, David. I personally feel down votes for answers in particular should carry reason.  Unfortunately some don't point the reason out.

Comment: Well, all I can do is try to continue to post good answers as best I can, take my medicine if I've posted something wrong, and if someone wants to downvote, there's not much to be done about it. After all, it's just virtual points that you can't spend anywhere, so as frustrating as it can be, I try not to get *too* frustrated over it :) If the mods see someone spamming downvotes, they'll deal with it. Have a great day :)

Comment: Well said, David. I agree.  Good day!

Comment: BTW, I think both of our answers were perfectly reasonable :)

Comment: True. That piques the mind.  It becomes  curious to know why someone felt otherwise. :)

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that TCP knows *nothing* about the context or semantics of your application-level messages. It's just shoveling around bits (well, packets).

What you are going to need to do is define some sort of *message exchange protocol* between your endpoints. Such a protocol must define either a fixed-length message format, or one that uses specific start and end characters to delineate beginning-of-message and end-of-message markers. Doing so will, in turn, will allow you to construct a read() loop that awaits a message conforming to the protocol, either via length or symbols - whatever your protocol defines.